Which levels are not available in Challenge Mode for Portal 2?
I have seen two levels that aren't available in Challenge Mode, namely "Container Ride" and "Portal Carousel" for Single Player.
And this link says that there are 11 levels in total that aren't available in Challenge Mode:

There are 11 levels in the singleplayer campaign that are not natively available in Challenge Mode.


I tried looking for a list of the ones that aren't available, but I couldn't find one. Does someone have a complete list of the levels that aren't available?

From The Cutting Room Floor's Challenge Mode section:




Map Name
Translation Token
Challenge Mode Name




Chapter 1




sp_a1_intro1
SP_MAP_NAME_CH1_MAP1
Container Ride


sp_a1_intro2
SP_MAP_NAME_CH1_MAP2
Portal Carousel


sp_a1_intro7
SP_MAP_NAME_CH1_MAP7
Secret Panel


sp_a1_wakeup
SP_MAP_NAME_CH1_MAP8
Wakeup


Chapter 2




sp_a2_laser_intro
SP_MAP_NAME_CH2_MAP1
Laser Intro


sp_a2_catapult_intro
SP_MAP_NAME_CH2_MAP5
Catapult Intro


Chapter 5




sp_a2_bts6
SP_MAP_NAME_CH5_MAP4
Tube Ride


sp_a2_core
SP_MAP_NAME_CH5_MAP5
Core


Chapter 6




sp_a3_00
SP_MAP_NAME_CH6_MAP1
Long Fall


Chapter 8




sp_a4_intro
SP_MAP_NAME_CH8_MAP1
Test


Chapter 9




sp_a4_finale1
SP_MAP_NAME_CH9_MAP1
Finale 1


Chapter 10




sp_a5_credits
SP_MAP_NAME_cH10_MAP1
Credits




As you can see, there are thirteen maps. Twelve of these are available for playing (as far as I can tell), but [my emphasis]:

In addition, if the player adds those maps to the Challenge Mode map list (Steam\SteamApps\common\Portal 2\portal2_dlc1\challenge_maplist.txt), the game makes use of those map names in the Challenge Mode menu (except the Credits map, which never appears). They are fully playable although they lack dedicated goal points. The "Level Completed" screen will come up when the player hits the level transition trigger. The Steam server correctly records the player's times and scores. The Community Data chart is also available on these maps, with the somewhat expected number of Fewest Portals records.

Here's a more precise guide on how to add these maps to Challenge Mode.

That entire page on Portal 2 is an interesting read, by the way!
